# pandas dataframe python - make the first row to be the last

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so I have a df that looks like this:

```
          2019   2018
Sally    -6461  -6340
Brian     7139   7200
rebecca   1337   1067
mark     10922  11128
toto     12936  13054
```

But I would like to make the first row to come at last like this:

```
          2019   2018
Brian     7139   7200
rebecca   1337   1067
mark     10922  11128
toto     12936  13054
Sally    -6461  -6340
```

How to achieve this?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[(df.index=='Sally').argsort()]
          2019   2018
Brian     7139   7200
rebecca   1337   1067
mark     10922  11128
toto     12936  13054
Sally    -6461  -6340
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! One question - Is there a way to achieve this without explicitly knowing the name of the index (e.g. Sally) in this case

Comment: @jinjineosj yes `df=df.iloc[1:].append(df.iloc[0])`